# Java - set result of java compiler in different directory

Tags: java, class

I was creating java compiler :

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(Arrays.asList("proccess\\test.java"));
JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, null,null, compilationUnits);
boolean success = task.call();
fileManager.close();
```

And I want result of compiler (class file) in another directory like `D:\proccess`.

How can I get the compiler to store its results in another directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the output directory in the `FileManager`:

```
fileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, Arrays.asList(new File("D:\proccess")));
```

Comment: sorry, i have long been answer. but it's not create class file in dir.

Comment: Omit the ``process`` folder, when you initialize your ``compilationUnits``. Simply put the ``test.java`` in there. Side note: Java class names and their corresponding file names should start with a capital letter, so you should rename ``test`` to ``Test``.

Comment: that's great, thanks. but it's not need renamed to capital letter.

Comment: Glad I could help you. The capitalization is a common naming convention in Java. You *can* name your classes differently, but you *should not*. See [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) for further reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can also pass the output directory via the compiler options:

```
JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(
    null,
    fileManager,
    diagnostics,
    Arrays.asList("-d", "C:/"),
    null,
    compilationUnits);
```

For a list of compiler options, see [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/JavaCompilerOptions.htm).

Comment: ``-d`` is an option for the Java compiler (``javac``) to set the destination directory for class files. See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#options) for further reference.

Comment: error on : `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid class name: -d`

Comment: The ``options`` array should be [fourth parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html#getTask(java.io.Writer,%20javax.tools.JavaFileManager,%20javax.tools.DiagnosticListener,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable)) of ``getTask()``, not fifth. Try swapping ``Arrays.asList("-d", "C:/")`` with its preceding line.

Comment: @Adriaan Koster: Fixed order of arguments in your answer.